# ShapeRenderer not drawing FilledRectangles behind Images

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm trying to draw FilledRectangles behind two different images using this code. But the ShapeRenderer isn't drawing anything.

```
public void render(float delta) {

    shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
    shapeRenderer.setColor(tankColor);
    shapeRenderer.rect(tankButton.x, tankButton.y,
            tankButton.width+50, tankButton.height+50);
    shapeRenderer.setColor(notesColor);
    shapeRenderer.rect(notesButton.x, notesButton.y,
            notesButton.width+50, notesButton.height+50);
    shapeRenderer.end();

    batch.begin();

    batch.draw(assetsLoader.backTexture, 0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);

    assetsLoader.shadow.draw(batch, " Touch for Sound !",
            Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2f - 150 + 5,
            200 + assetsLoader.font.getCapHeight() + 5, 400, Align.center, false);
    assetsLoader.font.draw(batch, " Touch for Sound !",
            Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2f - 150,
            200 + assetsLoader.font.getCapHeight(), 400, Align.center, false);



    // draw tank and notes image
    batch.draw(assetsLoader.tankTexture, tankButton.x, tankButton.y,
            tankButton.getWidth(), tankButton.getHeight());
    batch.draw(assetsLoader.notesTexture, notesButton.x, notesButton.y,
            notesButton.getWidth(), notesButton.getHeight());


    batch.end();


}
```

This is what I'm getting: [image]

This is what I need: [image]

Comment: You really ought to be using a Viewport and Camera. As for why you don't see your rectangles, it's because you're drawing your background after drawing the rectangles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. All I had to do was begin another batch after I inserted the Filled Rectangles. This is what I did:

```
public void render(float delta) {

    batch.begin();

    batch.draw(assetsLoader.backTexture, 0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);



    assetsLoader.shadow.draw(batch, " Touch for Sound !",
            Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2f - 150 + 5,
            200 + assetsLoader.font.getCapHeight() + 5, 400, Align.center, false);
    assetsLoader.font.draw(batch, " Touch for Sound !",
            Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2f - 150,
            200 + assetsLoader.font.getCapHeight(), 400, Align.center, false);


    batch.end();

    shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
    shapeRenderer.setColor(tankColor);
    shapeRenderer.rect(tankButton.x-25, tankButton.y-25,
            tankButton.width+50, tankButton.height+50);


    shapeRenderer.setColor(notesColor);
    shapeRenderer.rect(notesButton.x-25, notesButton.y-25,
            notesButton.width+50, notesButton.height+50);
    shapeRenderer.end();



    batch.begin();

    batch.draw(assetsLoader.tankTexture, tankButton.x, tankButton.y,
            tankButton.getWidth(), tankButton.getHeight());
    batch.draw(assetsLoader.notesTexture, notesButton.x, notesButton.y,
            notesButton.getWidth(), notesButton.getHeight());

    batch.end();
```